# PHP - Chat Socket working on localhost but not working on dedicated server

Tags: php, web-services, websocket, ratchet

The chat program runs fine while on localhost but when uploaded to server gives the error while connecting.
server file not working on the server, shows error while executing the code 
**$server = new Ratchet\App('wss://example.in', 8080);**
Sorry, im still new to the ratchet library and still trying to work out how to achieve this task.

The code from server.php file

```
  <?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    
    class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
        protected $clients;
    
        public function __construct() {
            $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        }
        
        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
            $this->clients->attach($conn);
        }
        
        public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
            $this->clients->detach($conn);
        }
        
        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from,  $data) {
            $from_id = $from->resourceId;
            $data = json_decode($data);
            $type = $data->type;
            switch ($type) {
            case 'chat':
                $user_id = $data->user_id;
                $chat_msg = $data->chat_msg;
                $response_from = "<span style='color:#999'><b>".$user_id.":</b> ".$chat_msg."</span>";
                $response_to = "<b>".$user_id."</b>: ".$chat_msg."";
                // Output
                $from->send(json_encode([
                    "type"=>$type,"msg"=>$response_from
                ]));
                foreach($this->clients as $client) {
                    if($from!=$client) {
                        $client->send(json_encode([
                            "type"=>$type,"msg"=>$response_to
                        ]));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
    $server = new Ratchet\App('wss://example.in', 8080);
    $server->route('/', new Chat, ['*']);
    $server->run();
    ?>
```

Code from index.php

```
<?php $session = mt_rand(1,999); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:arial,sans-serif;resize:none;}
    html,body {width:100%;height:100%;}
    #wrapper {position:relative;margin:auto;max-width:1000px;height:100%;}
    #chat_output {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;padding:20px;width:100%;height:calc(100% - 100px);}
    #chat_input {position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;padding:10px;width:100%;height:100px;border:1px solid #ccc;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="chat_output"></div>
        <textarea id="chat_input" placeholder="Deine Nachricht..."></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            // Websocket
            var websocket_server = new WebSocket("wss://example.in:8080/");
            websocket_server.onopen = function(e) {
                websocket_server.send(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        'type': 'socket',
                        'user_id': <?=$session?>,
                    })
                );
            };
            websocket_server.onerror = function(e) {
                // Errorhandling
            }
            websocket_server.onmessage = function(e) {
                var json = JSON.parse(e.data);
                switch(json.type) {
                    case 'chat':
                        $('#chat_output').append(json.msg);
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Events
            $('#chat_input').on('keyup',function(e){
                if(e.keyCode==13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                    var chat_msg = $(this).val();
                    websocket_server.send(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            'type': 'chat',
                            'user_id': <?=$session?>,
                            'chat_msg': chat_msg
                        })
                    );
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what error are you getting, precisely?

Comment: P.S. Please read [ask] and [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Have you tried using Ip Address of the server ?

Comment: It gives HTTP ERROR 500 @ADyson

Comment: Yes I have tried using IP Address @AnkitPrajapati

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the specific problem.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Invalid domain in /vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/FlashPolicy.php:62

Ratchet\Server\FlashPolicy->addAllowedAccess('wss://example.in', 80)